# Including AWS function call removes app layout

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

This is a picture of my react app before and after replacing a method handleSubmit from the following:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

with this:

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    await Auth.signIn(email, password);
    alert("Logged in");
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

[image]

As you can see the replacement of code removes the 'layout' of the app-page. I am new to AWS and React. Anyone has a clue what is wrong?

The entire Login.js container can be seen here:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import "./Login.css";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";


export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  function validateForm() {
    return email.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
  }

async function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    await Auth.signIn(email, password);
    alert("Logged in");
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
  }
}

  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            autoFocus
            type="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button block size="lg" type="submit" disabled={!validateForm()}>
          Login
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole code of your react component since I don't see why is this happening.

Comment: I added code for the entire Login.js. If I comment out the line await Auth.signIn(email, password);, then the 'layout' is still visible. So the error is something to do with that

Comment: It's probably something to do with your amplify configuration. try reinstalling amplify, and re-adding amplify auth